# Why does a category have a weird path defined in the Magento database?

Tags: magento

My `catalog_category_entity` table has an entry for a category that does not appear anywhere in the admin area of the site, or in the front end.

It has a weird path: "/30" (30 is its `entity_id`). Every other category in every other Magento site I have access to starts its path with a number, not a slash.

It has entries through the rest of the EAV system in various places.

My suspicion is that someone ran a bad import, or other manual process, which left this category in the database, when really it should have been simply deleted.

Is this an anomaly, or is there a reason for this category to have a weird path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suspicion is right. Most probably this is due to a bad import. Normally all paths look like this: `1/2/5/17`. The path represents the ids of the categories starting from "root of all roots" (1) and continuing with all the parents and last is the category id. The path is used for displaying the categories in frontend and backend. That's why the category does not appear in any list.
If you have data on that category and you need it, just edit the path field and make it `1/2/30`.  `2` is the id of the root catalog so it may be different for you.
Then just increment the field `children_count` for the categories with id 1 and 2.
Back-up your db before trying this.

Comment: OK, thanks. I modified the path to add a 1 at the start, then deleted it through the Magento admin interface, and all seems fine.